# Make sure section is above the fold in css

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

i have a website with a simple hero type image ( or banner ), a navigation header and a search-input-container that can be of **variable size** depending on some settings.

==== 
|||||||||
|||||||||
;;;;;;;;;

this translates to 

-navigation header 
-banner image
-search container

I would like all those 3 containers to always be above the folder and fit perfectly on the user's screen.

The navigation menu is always 10% per cent of screen viewport height

The search-container is calculated on the server and arrives at variable heights
Example, the search container may have 2 search textboxes one ontop of another or just 1.

The banner image is the only image that i want to fill the left-over space, after the searchcontainer and navigation menu took its fair share of size.

```
<div style="height:100vh;display: flex; flex-direction: column">
<div style="background-color:red;height:150px">navigation menu (always 150px)u</div>

<div style="background-color:antiquewhite;height: 200px;"> hero image image ( this must take over the space left over in the viewport ) after the nav menu and bottom space took their share</div>

<div style="background-color:aqua;min-height: 405px;"> variable height container can be 400px or 600px depending on what it contains</div>
```

http://cssdeck.com/labs/gemoy4ga

Comment: What is all that punctuation at the beginning of your question?

Comment: i pust a cssdeck to get a better idea of what I am talking about.

Comment: everything is fine in your code just make second div height:100%;
and see, I think This is what you want

like this

<div style="background-color:antiquewhite;height: 100%;"> hero image ( image ( this must take over the space left over in the viewport )</div>

Answer (score 1):

First, using inline styles with the `style=` attribute makes your code extremely difficult to manage. I recommend using classes and an actual stylesheet. I have done so in my code sample below.

You control which elements grow and shrink with the size of the flex-box using the `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` properties:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink

Here's my implementation:

```css
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100vh;
}
.wrapper .nav{
  flex-shrink:0;
  flex-grow:0;
  height:10%;
  
  background-color:red;
}
.wrapper .hero{
  flex-grow:1;
  
  background-color:antiquewhite;
}
.wrapper .search{
  height:400px;

  background-color:aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="nav">navigation menu (always 150px)u</div>

    <div class="hero">hero image ( this must take over the occupied space</div>

    <div class="search">variable height container can be 400px or 600px depending on what it contains</div>
</div>
```

Note that you have said that the nav should be both "always 150px" and "10% of the viewport height". I wasn't sure which you actually wanted, so went with the latter.

Comment: I was about to post the same answer, but you beat me to it. kudos! The only thing to add, which you see clearly when you run the snippet, is that for small screens, the hero image will virtually disappear unless you set a height, which can be provided by an `img` within the hero div. However, you will have issues on screen resizing. If you use a `background-image` instead, your div could completely collapse.

Comment: Yes, my preference would be to use a `background-image` and to set a minimum height of the `hero`... But that wasn't specified as a requirement. ;)

Comment: I'm with you. I upvoted your answer as right on. I added an answer below just to demonstrate to @Aflred the issues at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Below are two approaches to solving your problem, by adding a `flex` value on the `hero` image container.

Since the outer `div` is has `flex-direction: column`, you can use the `flex` property on it's children to determine whether they will shrink, grow, stay the same, and set a flex-basis. See here for a good run-down: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

However, you also need to determine some minimum height for your hero image because you will face two problems. The examples below show two issues you will face along with the solution.

There are two examples below to demonstrate problems you will have with the hero image approach.

**First, embedding a hero image as a responsive image:**

This will keep the image height, even on smaller screens (as whatever the height of the image would be at that image's width.)

However, on larger screens, you need to make sure you use an image with enough height to fill the `.hero` div.

See the snippet below and be sure to click on the 'Full Page' to see the extra white-space

```css
.container {
    height:100vh;
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column
}

.nav {
    background-color:red;
    flex: 0 0 150px;
    height: 10%;
}

.hero {
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

.variable {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    background-color:aqua;
    min-height: 405px;
    max-height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="nav">
      navigation menu (always 150px)u
  </div>

  <div class='hero'>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x200/?text=Hero+Image" class='img-responsive'>
  </div>

  <div class='variable'> 
      variable height container can be 400px or 600px depending on what it contains
  </div>
</div>
```

**Second, setting a background image on the `hero` div**

Here the hero image will collapse on small screens since your nav and your variable height div will take up all the space.

```css
.container {
    height:100vh;
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column
}

.nav {
    background-color:red;
    flex: 0 0 150px;
    height: 10%;
}

.hero {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1280x200/?text=Hero+Image);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
}

.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

.variable {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    background-color:aqua;
    min-height: 405px;
    max-height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="nav">
      navigation menu (always 150px)u
  </div>

  <div class='hero'>
      
  </div>

  <div class='variable'> 
      variable height container can be 400px or 600px depending on what it contains
  </div>
</div>
```

The solution for either case must include `media queries` to account for changes to the height of the hero block based on screen size. For the `background-image` approach, you can add a `height` to the `hero` div to fit your desired outcome.

**One Possible Approach**

Add a `flex-basis` to the hero-image. I chose `200px` and set the `flex-shrink` value to `0`. On larger screens, I just want to make sure my image is large enough not to look stretched, as it does here.

```css
.container {
    height:100vh;
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column
}

.nav {
    background-color:red;
    flex: 0 0 150px;
    height: 10%;
}

.hero {
    flex: 1 0 200px;
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1280x200/?text=Hero+Image);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    
}

.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

.variable {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    background-color:aqua;
    min-height: 405px;
    max-height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="nav">
      navigation menu (always 150px)u
  </div>

  <div class='hero'>
      <!-- Background Image Approach -->
  </div>

  <div class='variable'> 
      variable height container can be 400px or 600px depending on what it contains
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may be covering some critical issues, however that is not the OP's question, now imagine someone googling this question, you're answer would not be relavent. it would be better as a comment, with some jsfiddle examples.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I appreciate that comment. As I mentioned in a comment on RobertAKARobin 's response that I was adding this to demonstrate what needs to be added to get the flexbox approach to work properly. I don't intend to supplant that response, in fact, i upvoted it. I feel there's got to be room to add further discussion besides the comments, but that's not how SO is set up, I suppose

Comment: @ZohirSalak I added some clarification to show that I'm answering his question directly as well as adding additional cases to consider.

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  flex: 0 0 150px; /* don't grow, don't shrink, fixed at 150px height */
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  flex: 1; /* flex-grow: 1, flex-shrink: 1, flex-basis: 0 */
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

footer {
  flex: 1 0 400px;   /* min-height: 400px and can expand */
  max-height: 600px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>navigation menu (always 150px)</header>
  <main>hero image (this must take over the occupied space)</main>
  <footer>variable height container can be 400px or 600px depending on what it containers</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: if i were to guess, it's because a code dumb, i up-voted just in case.

Comment: Thanks. But I posted my explanation as CSS comments. @wlh

Comment: I never thought you did. Your answer was useful. I already upvoted it. @wlh